# Is an index required for columns in ON clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, postgresql, query-optimization

Do I have to create an index on columns referenced in Joins?
E.g.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  left_table
INNER JOIN
  right_table
ON
  left_table.foo = right_table.bar
WHERE
  ...
```

Should I create indexes on left_table(foo), right_table(bar), or both?

I noticed different results when I used EXPLAIN (Postgresql) with and without indexes and switching around the order of the comparison

```
(right_table.bar = left_table.foo)
```

I know for sure that indexes are used for the left of the WHERE clause but I am wondering whether I need indexes for columns listed in ON clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your `where` condition, but brief answer is `yes`.

Usually left table would have this column as primary key which is an index by default.
The second column would be a foreign key and it is likely your queries will benefit from the index added for this column. You need to analyze your query to tell for sure if you need the index or not.

Let say the query is like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM  left_table
   INNER JOIN right_table ON
      left_table.foo = right_table.bar
WHERE left_table.SomeField = 1
```

Index on `right_table.bar` will definitely be used.

On the other side:

```
SELECT  *
FROM  left_table
   INNER JOIN right_table ON
      left_table.foo = right_table.bar
WHERE right_table.SomeField = 1
```

In this case index on `right_table.bar` will not be used at all, but index on `left_table.foo` will.

Comment: The merge join algorithm will generally run faster with indexes on both sides of the ON condition.  For large cardinality joins, this may be the fastest strategy. Without the second index, the optimizer may not even pick the merge join strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Ususally on the left you'll have a primary key, so no index needed there. But on the right you'll typically have a foreign key - which it could make sense to index.

Comment: Thanks.. I feel bad not accepting your answer but the above answerer wrote a lot more. I rewarded him for his effort:)